# For Loop but skipping lines

Tags: r, loops

Sorry, not sure if this was asked before. I am trying to do a for loop, but have it skip every 2 lines. My current code is not working

#here is my data and code

```
test = as.data.frame(cbind(rep(NA,10), rep(NA,10)))

for (i in 1:10){ 
  test[i,1] = 1 
  i = i+2
  }
```

my data looks like

```
V1 V2
1   1 NA
2   1 NA
3   1 NA
4   1 NA
5   1 NA
6   1 NA
7   1 NA
8   1 NA
9   1 NA
10  1 NA
```

but I want it to look like

```
 V1 V2
1   1  NA
2   NA NA
3   1  NA
4   NA NA
5   1  NA
6   NA NA
7   1  NA
8   NA NA
9   1  NA
10  NA NA
```

Answer (score 2):

The loop can be changed to:

```
for (i in seq(from=1, to=10, by=2)){ 
  test[i,1] = 1 
}
```

alternatively this can be done without a `for` loop using vectorization as:

```
test[seq(from=1, to=10, by=2),1] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks but my loop is a little complicated than what I posted. I have an if statement in the loop, is there just another way to change the number "i" is on?

Answer (score 1):

Taking from [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69001170/for-loop-but-skipping-lines#comment121949751_69001232) about more-complicated in-loop processing ...

Unlike other languages, in R one cannot update the loop variable `i` mid-loop, the update will be lost on the next loop. For that, you need to shift to a more-general `while` loop.

```r
i <- 1L
while (i <= nrow(test)) {
  if (some_condition) {
    i <- i + 2L
  } else {
    # default behavior, most similar to the `for` loop
    i <- i + 1L
  }
  test[i,1] = 1
}
```